# print out the keywords in color in shell script by ANSI

Tags: bash, shell

I have been provided a txt file and a keyword. How can I write a shell script to print the content of a txt file with all the keywords in the file highlighted. I must use  "\e[1mthe text\e[m".

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for 
tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and **free code** are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106565/45365

Comment: @PengCheng : I wouldn't do this kind of text processing in pure bash. It can be done, but it's a bit clumsy. You are basically asking for how to replace one word (the keyword) by another word (the keyword surrounded by some markup strings). The canonical tool for this is `sed`, but you can also use any programming language with good text manipulation operators, such as `awk` or `Ruby` or `Perl`.